# How can I encourage a culture of punctuality in a software company?

Tags: software-industry, company-culture

As a new technical lead in a new company, what are some additional strategies to employ to change the culture of the development team so that people show up at the time that I've requested?

**TLDR**:  My team doesn't show up on time.  I've tried to compel them and it isn't working.

Background Data:

1. Small company, 30 employees, 5 members of my team.
2. The previous lead is still on staff as a regular developer.
3. The culture prior to my arrival was one of informality with no set boundaries or core hours.  This culture was not challenged by the corporate leaders.  Most people on the team would show up between 10:30 and 11:00 because of this.
4. Other departments, due to the nature of their work, have set start times of either 8 or 9.

This discrepancy and unpredictability causes a lot of angst between my department and other departments.  As such, I sat the team down and specified a 'no later than' time of 9:30.  I explained my reasoning and I explained the benefits of such a scheme and the negatives of the current scheme.  It was a long and contentious conversation and 3 of the 5 people on the team were quite displeased.

Needless to say, people aren't showing up on time (and 9:35 is not on time.)

I've scheduled our daily standup meeting at 9:30 as an added motivator.  Knowing that it takes a little bit of time to transition start times (with commute, etc...) I initially would wait to begin the meeting until everyone showed up, but now I just start the meeting (and often finish the meeting) with whomever is present.  That seems to not be making a difference either and it's making the team less cohesive.

Conversations on an individual and group basis yield the same results as the original conversation (i.e. they don't see the value, think I'm taking away a perk of the job, etc...)

I have the full support and backing of the senior management team and am empowered to employ whatever devices I feel appropriate to get this taken care of.

My current next step is to send someone home and make them take the day off.  Is that too drastic?  Are there alternative strategies that I'm overlooking that could help me solve this problem?

### Edit based on questions in Jarrod's answer

**How new of a technical lead?**  6 months, at this company,  at the time of this question.

**Why are you imposing purely non-technical managerial policies?** It is in the scope of my position as defined by executive management.

**What are your management credentials?** 10 years experience as a technical lead. No formal education or certification in anything managerial.

**What previous personnel management experience do you have?**  I have been a technical lead for 10 years.  I've been responsible for hiring/firing/interviewing/reviewing/leading/building a few different technical teams.

**Have you earned the respect of the team in a technical manner?**  Yes

**Have you earned the respect of the team in a managerial manner?** I was interviewed for technical and managerial ability by the team.  I was clear and straightforward about how I like to run technical teams and how I like to run projects (with the obvious caveat that that is just a starting point and culture and personnel ultimately influence where I land.)  There are many things, from a managerial perspective, that the team is quite happy with.

**Did the previous technical lead step down?**  Yes.

**Was the previous technical lead demoted?**  No.  It was his request.

**Was the previous technical lead effective?**  For a time.  But, growth of the company and the codebase made his style ineffective.

**Does the majority of the existing team have a more personal relationship with the previous technical lead?**  Yes.

**Is the previous technical lead effectively still in charge?**  No.

**Then [the previous culture of informality with no set boundaries] must have been working?**  It worked for a time, when the company was still a startup.  It has grown and evolved well beyond the startup phase and, due to that growth, is not nearly as effective as it once was.  Especially as other departments have introduced a bit more formality and predictability.

**Was the team successful in delivering useful products when promised?**  At the beginning.  But, as the company and the product grew, quality and delivery times slipped significantly.

**Doesn't sound like you even considered or explored some kind of compromise with your team or the external teams based on their negative feed back. Did you?**  Of course I have, I'm not a rookie.  The fact of the matter is, I respect the fact that the rest of the company works in an inflexible box due to the nature of their responsibilities.  The team was unwilling to compromise on their flex time and, in many cases, the other departments are unable to compromise.  I have also addressed the negative feedback specifically with the other departments and implemented a number of things to make things better.  One of the big benefits of this change was to improve predictability and change perceptions.

### Final Update

From the original crew of 5, 2 have been replaced.  The first was the previous team lead.  We could not see eye-to-eye on how to run development projects and he could not accept changes to what he had previously laid down, so we mutually agreed to part ways.  The second lost interest in the work, made a couple of big mistakes and we also mutually agreed to part ways.

The team, as a whole, now shows up early enough to ensure plenty of coverage for the rest of the company.  What ultimately worked was mandate and peer pressure.  In addition, other changes that have been instituted have resulted in nearly all of the inter-departmental angst to be resolved.  Everyone still gets to work on awesome projects, mostly of their choosing, at their own pace at an exciting company and they are all quite content despite the job market being ridiculous in the area.

I have been promoted to an executive position and the new 'problem team' has been moved under me (in addition to still retaining control of the dev team and still developing.)  I'm now working to help them perform better and be better teammates to their colleagues.  I don't have the punctuality issue with this new team... Their issues are accuracy and communication.

Comment: Maybe a different kind of motivator, such as a doughnut *only* for those who shows up on-time or early. It might get expensive to do daily, so maybe only do it once a week, but don't tell them *which* day... ;) I've never tried this, so that's why I'm posting as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: One important thing is missing from this question: ***WHY*** are you making this change? Is work not getting done in a timely manner? Is there an actual problem that needs solving (and is this the right way to solve it? Might be a subject for another question...)  As Andrew pointed out in his answer, dictating an arbitrary "not-after" start time to knowledge employees who already have a flex-time culture is going to be unpopular, and it's hard to suggest motivators/methodology without more context...

Comment: @voretaq7: I think that "This discrepancy and unpredictability causes a lot of angst between my department and other departments" means that other departments need to be in touch with OP's dept. and when one group comes in at 9 am and depends on others who who won't show up until 11-ish or so, it causes problems.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Quite possibly but then if the developer puts the work on the designer's desk at 8pm to be tested between 9 and 11 tomorrow morning I see no issue. I prefer coordination over arbitrary rules. I'm also trying not to make assumptions, but the "angst" could just as easily be "Sales is crying because they want to come in late too and if they can't nobody can!"

Comment: Are you willing to enforce the flip side of your 'school bell' rule?  

Everyone stops what they are doing and leaves at a time certain no matter how much work might still be undone?

Comment: @JimInTexas it's more of a "Core Hours" rule.  You must be in the office between 9:30 - 4:00 ... you can swing earlier or later as your choose.

Comment: @voretaq7, in the corporate world, a manager has to act when other departments are complaining. The employees in those departments don't see why they have to be there at set hours and the devs do not. I'm sure he has been directed to fix the problem.

Comment: @HLGEM That depends on the nature of the complaint though: Sometimes the right action as a manager is to tell the other departments "This is how my team works, and it works for the company. Tough Rocks." -- In Jacob's case though his devs seem to be spoiled prima donnas with attitude problems [see this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4208458#4208458) and some of the comments below...

Comment: Reading through the question, comments and chat it isn't clear to me exactly where the motivation for this 'perk removal' lies between "we need to coordinate between departments" and "other departments are jealous of our perk". Probably stating the obvious, but if your developers feel that the first reason is just a façade for the second, the reaction you're getting is completely predictable: while you're at it, why not drop their salaries to align with other departments? If it really is the 'coordination' problem, is it a problem every single day? If not, there must be other possible solution

Comment: @JacobG: So people in other departments *need* to have face-to-face meetings with the developers on your team on a regular basis, so much so that having the developers come into work at 11am seriously interferes with that? Why is so much face-to-face cross-department interaction necessary? *Is* it necessary? Is attending these meetings really a good use of your developers' time, or can coordination take place on a higher level (say, between *you* and other departments)? I'm not doubting your description of the situation, but it seems odd.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The interaction between departments is frequent and often due to collaborative need.  We're a small company and a small dev team and we need to wear multiple hats in the SDLC, support our production environments and help the other departments meet their deliverables as well.  Many of us in the company have time-sensitive things to deliver and there usually isn't enough lead time to spend days coordinating.  I run interference the best I can, but I can't take it all on myself and need the rest of the team to be available.

Comment: *Needless to say, people aren't showing up on time (and 9:35 is not on time.)* this sounds dictatorial, micro-managing and tyrannical. Sounds like you need minions; look for those personality types when the current crew quits.

Comment: The moment you say:  (and 9:35 is not on time.) immediately give me the impression you are a harsh boss and I would less likely to listen to what you say. Programmers pretty much everywhere have always have work hour flexibility, and most of the time people falls to a routine, it's unlikely they are unpredictable when they gonna come. People do this mostly because of what work best for them and in turn that makes them more productive.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson and tsoverflow - You guys are obviously welcome to your opinions but I think you're a little out of bounds with your hyperbole.  I am neither 'tyrannical' nor 'douchy,' but I expect people to show up to meetings on time and be ready to participate.

Comment: Still sounds like the problem is with *you* not the rest of the team. You have a dictatorial tone here, I can only imagine how you come across to the people that you are supposed to be *leading*. The feeling I get is this is either your first or second time in this position and you think they should just do like you say because you are in charge. There is a culture in place for good or bad; you need to adapt to it and change it by example from the inside. You came here asking for help, but don't want to listen to anyones opinions. This should really be *How can I bend my employees to my will?*

Comment: breakfast spread of bagels, donuts, coffee, etc. pack it all away at 9:30am

Comment: I don't know what you all think but arguing over five minutes is not really an effective nor productive way to spend your time with the team.

Comment: @Spoike - It might just be 5 minutes but they are still late.  If they can't even show up on TIME 9/10 times then how can the author trust them?

Comment: @Ramhound: Whenever I have people coming in late for meetings I honestly **don't care**. I end up talking to people who are in on time (discussing the day, life, whatever... you know... getting to know them better) and then get on with the real business when everyone has arrived. Trust is something you earn through your interactions with other people. Penalization (while it looks good on Hollywood blockbuster movies) is not how you build up your trust with them.

Comment: @Spoike I would say being habitually late *for meetings* betrays a lack of respect for others' time that should be addressed.  The company shouldn't be paying five people to sit around twiddling thumbs making small talk waiting for everyone to arrive.
There's value to *some* small talk, etc., but a culture where the business of a meeting doesn't start until several minutes after the scheduled start time indicates that time isn't valued and respected.

Comment: @tsOverflow: If the stand-up meeting is at 9h30 sharp, then you just have to schedule your arrival for 9h25 and you can afford being 5 minutes late in case of issue.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: OP decided to make everyone come at 9:30am first, then he purposely scheduled the meeting at 9:30am to compel everyone come early. There's the difference between scheduling the meeting early purposely like that vs actually have a meeting at that time without the underlying intention of making people come at certain time.

Comment: @JohnMcG: Coming in as a new manager to disrupt things without letting anyone have a mandate on it is big deal, a sign that you don't listen and a sign of disrespect. Changes like this takes time, even years. Try to start respecting others before *demanding* respect. From the edit: His team is unwilling to compromise the flex time which I guess because they have a vested interest in it and probably signed up for that kind of work. Whatever the reason, it is your job as a manager to deal with it and manage expectations... or sack the team... but that is a bad solution.

Comment: @JacobG: From the chat discussion linked by voretaq7, it looks as though your situation could be summarised as "I have to lead a department of spoilt prima donnas who don't do the work properly, have bad relations with other departments and come in late" - in such a situation, "come in late" is the *least of your problems*. You may be able to use this to your advantage, however - if you can agree with senior management that punctuality can be relaxed in return for improvements in other areas, *and* present this as a quid pro quo to your team, you *may* get improvements all around.

Comment: @Spoike - It sounds like you would be very difficult to work with.  You don't seem to think "being late" in the eyes of the supervisor is a problem.  It doesn't matter what the policy was with the old supervisor to be honest.  If they don't like said changes, they are welcome to leave, and the new supervisor can replace them with people who WILL be on time.

Comment: @Ramhound: Now you're making assumptions that aren't there and is much uncalled for. I'm usually on time for meetings, and even prefer to be there some minutes before and usually easy to work with, at least that's what my colleagues tell me on my LinkedIn profile. :-) All I'm saying is that even if someone comes in late for a meeting I don't want spend all my cognitive energy on bickering about it, there are much more pressing matters to attend to.

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why losing an hour or two window in the morning is so disastrous to coordination with other departments. If your devs are spending more than an hour a day doing this sort of a thing, that's an indicator to me of a serious management(not OP's necessarily) or a culture problem. If the devs are being prima donas it's possible they're all jerks. It's also possible somebody has them in hours of meetings a day for constant progress updates on all the work they can't even get to until after 5 when everybody else leaves. I've been there/seen that colossal waste of dev salaries.

Comment: *I have the full support and backing of the senior management team and am empowered to employ whatever devices I feel appropriate to get this taken care of.* - And you think that this will help you impose a culture of punctuality? Good luck, dude.

Comment: @JimG. That was merely potentially relevant information that someone may have used to formulate a productive solution to 'encourage' not 'impose' a culture of punctuality.  Feel free to participate in the community and offer your own productive solution.

Comment: The question is an oxymoron....

Comment: The intensity of a programmer's workday is incomparable to the one of the workers in other department, therefore they cannot be treated equally. For instance, if your job is reviewing a couple of CVs, or making a phone call, of course you have to be there from 9am to 5pm. I mean, there are jobs where you don't have challenging tasks, but your presence is needed all day long, and there are others where you have a deadline and an amount of work to do before that, regardless of when you come in the morning.

Comment: *"I've scheduled our daily standup meeting at 9:30 as an added motivator..."* - you call this a *"motivation"*? OMG..

Comment: Is there any reason you have to underline that you are the one who decides things on your team?

Comment: OP sounds like a dictator.  "Why are you imposing purely non-technical managerial policies? It is in the scope of my position as defined by executive management." Power-trip much?

Comment: "We hired lots of people on the cheap in exchange for super flexible work hours. Now that they took the bait we'd like to switch."

If you want "punctuality" put the (core) working hours in the contract.

Comment: I am new to the site and I'd just like to leave this note here: as a dev, I would like to know what company the OP worked for at the time he asked this question, so I never send my resumé to them.

Comment: I was wondering why there was "angst" in the other departments.  Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen They were probably playing Bright Eyes in their department.

Comment: If *they […] think I'm taking away a perk of the job* it's because you are. It might also be justified, necessary, unreasonable, dictatorial but it is what it is regardless.

Comment: So the reason for the early start is that other departments are jealous? Perhaps you need to look at why 9-5 became a standard in the first place, and the many reasons why it no longer applies to most software developers in the age of telecommuting...

Comment: I'm reminded of the _Tao of Programming_, book 6, section 4.

Answer (score 156):

**The best motivating factor is trust.**  Team unity is of ultimate importance in accomplishing your goals.  Rule cultures are bred of distrust, and sticks and prods to enforce rules will only further erode trust from your team.

Rather than being concerned over exact times and informal cultures, try figuring out what the intrinsic values are.

- Does 9:30 (or any arbitrary time) really matter? **Or** is it that your team needs to make sure they are not hindering the work of other teams by their absence?
- Does 5 minutes make a difference? **Or** is it most important that all members join in the daily standup?
- Is informality a problem? **Or** is flexibility a benefit?

I would dig at the core of the issue, which is that your team hasn't bought into the idea.  See where the disconnect is, but **avoid creating a rules culture**.  Sending them home for being late (a disciplinary tactic you'd find in an elementary school) will lead your team to believe you see them as children who can't be trusted.

Comment: +1 - I think this is the most concise way to phrase the problem *and* the solutions.  Whatever rules you set need to facilitate getting things done, and that's how this should be approached with the employees.

Comment: I like this answer and I do agree with it.  I believe I did attempt to get them to understand the underlying issues and how they would be helped with a Core Hours policy.  One dev responded with superiority (i.e. screw the other departments b/c I'm special) and the others focused solely on the loss of a perk.  I don't believe they see themselves as a piece of the larger team, rather as the superstar of the larger team.  I don't want to "send them home," that's why I asked for some alternative tactics as I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @JacobG You know, the second developer _does_ have a point - being able to come in between 10:30 and 11:00 am **is** a perk, even if it's one you don't approve of them using (like, e.g, smoke breaks). You shouldn't remove it without offering some form of compensation.

Comment: +1 absolutely agree. I would add that perhaps the problem can be mitigated by considering having "coverage" during core hours rather than having _everyone_ on-site at core hours. Can some devs volunteer to show-up earlier while others stay later?

Comment: I agree with the motivation factor but I disagree that a rules culture is a bad thing.

Comment: when people have bad habits, rewarding / compensating them for giving them up is not great.  I'd rather reward and compensate for results.

Comment: Some good points but I disagree with your premise. Trust, not distrust, enables rules cultures. The OP's problem is that his reports don't trust him enough to do what he's asking of them. They may be right not to do so. So, rather **The best motivating factor is self interest.**

Comment: This isn't a problem about * trust* it is a problem about *respect* and someones direct manager supporting their opinion respecting it and making sure their voice is being heard. Read the comments on my answer, there is no belief that the dev team should have a voice in the matter, it is a dictatorial approach not an insular approach to management.

Comment: As a team lead or line manager working with smart, creative people, the most important skill is listening.  As long as the team is productive and effective, don't get in their way.  In this case the pressure is from outside of the team - I see my role as *protecting* the team from this kind of "organisational rain" and so tend to end up fighting for them with management, not the other way round.  If the team is efficient and productive, then don't mess with it.  If the timekeeping breaks down team cohesion, then ensure it is raised in your retrospectives as an issue for the team to resolve.

Comment: +1 for focusing on the core issue and avoiding creating a rules culture. The point about flexibility as a benefit is also a good one.

Answer (score 124):

Creating a culture of punctuality may take time and may be something you have to compromise on somewhat. Since you're dealing with intelligent knowledge workers, you'll be more successful if you can get them to buy into the plan. Instead of focusing on the time, focus on the problem created by the scheduling issues.

Present the problem as a challenge to the team and see what they come up with. The answer may be set schedules or it may be something different that solves the problem. It may be Monday, Wednesday, Friday are the 9am-sharp days while Tuesday and Thursday are the flex days. While the plan may not be perfect nor will it be exactly what you envisioned, finding a middle ground somewhere that will make both the development team happy, as well as solve the actual problem will prevent your staff from becoming bitter and seeing you as the enemy.

Keep in mind that you're not dealing with a manufacturing process where everyone must show up at exactly 9:30am, when the whistle blows, so they can begin the mind-numbing task of assembling the same little plastic widgets repeatedly, until the whistle blows again, and the mind-numbed staff make their way out to the local bar for happy hour.

> My team doesn't show up on time. I've tried to compel them and it isn't working.

Forcing smart people never works. You need to remember that you're dealing with highly educated, smart, creative people who are good at solving complex, abstract, and unique problems. These people, at least the really good ones, will never just blindly follow orders. This goes back to putting the problem in their hands, at least at first. If they do nothing, then you'll want to step in with your own solution.

You mentioned that you're a new team lead. Stepping into a new position like this is challenging and stressful as you're not sure how to gain respect of the team and also be a good leader. This comes with experience, and it's common for inexperienced new team leads to attempt to "compel" or force people to do things their way. This is not leadership.

Developers, and other knowledge workers, don't need a manager; instead, they need a leader. Great leaders inspire others to do great things, and this is your opportunity to lead your team to greatness rather than dictate it into despair.

Research shows that people are more likely to commit when they have participated in determining what the solution will be rather than have that solution *told* to them, and this is *especially* true with knowledge workers.

For inspiration, please see Seth Godin's Interview on the [Difference Between Leadership and Management](http://michaelhyatt.com/seth-godin-on-the-difference-between-leadership-and-management.html).  I highly recommend that anyone and everyone in a leadership capacity watch this short interview.

Comment: "Let them come up with a plan" was my first reaction too. However, judging from comments and chat, that doesn't seem likely to work in this particular case...

Comment: @Benjol - The tone of the question makes me think there is more to this than meets the eye. It feels too Theory X style management, which isn't effective when managing developers. We're only hearing one side of the story, and the truth is always somewhere in the middle.

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: The most important point is this:  _Forcing smart people never works_.  You can't treat your highly intelligent team members like children and expect them to not complain, fight back, and resent you for it (case in point; I'm not directly affected by any of this but I still find it hard not to take personal offense at how the OP is trying to manage his team).  Technical employees are generally about as smart as their managers (if not more so), so the only effective way to approach them is as peers, not as mindless underlings who should do what you say because you said it.

Comment: I'm poorly educated and still object to people taking my flex time away.

Answer (score 63):

It's been my experience that knowledge workers don't like being dictated to about policies for which they *see* no purpose.  You do state a purpose, but the employees you are managing seem to think it is not a good one.  Further, there are probably alternatives that you have not considered, and given what sounds like an issue being "dictated from above," your employees may either not have thought of them, do not feel comfortable proposing them, or feel that they would simply be shot down.

If the only reason you are implementing the policy is because of tension with people in other departments, it's your job to manage that tension so that your people can work most effectively.  I don't think that's the only reason, though.  For example, what if a developer is needed to fix an urgent production issue that happens at 8:00 or 9:00 or whatever other time?  However, it is unlikely that you need *all* your developers present to fix that issue.  What if you had a rotating (unless someone volunteers) "early" schedule, so that each developer takes a turn being required to be there at 8:00 (or 9:00, etc.)?  That solution seems more likely to satisfy both the business needs and the desires of your employees.  Everyone "shares the pain" (or inflicts it on someone who doesn't mind it).  People can come in and work most of the time when they feel they would be most productive.  This is just one possibility, but it may generate discussion with your employees about how to solve the real problems and satisfy everyone's interests here.

If you choose to go down the more disciplinary route, and the "start time" issue truly is important to your developers, you will lose your good ones to other employment.  Your employees are likely to feel insecure in their jobs (what if some real emergency actually happens one day to make someone late?).  Further, this can be seen as a shift in management in the wrong direction (from your employees' perspective), since they did previously have experience working under someone else.

It's up to you, of course, but I would urge you to take a step back and try harder to see the situation from your employees' perspective.  You have a job to do, of course, but I think there are solutions that better satisfy everyone's interests than the one you are proposing.

Comment: I'm not going to penalize someone if they have a legit reason for arriving late.  Oversleeping three times a week because they're playing WoW all night isn't legit.  We have an early person who prefers to show up at 7:30.  The big issue is that if Dev X is working on a project with Designer Y and Designer Y is in at 8, he's waiting until 1pm or later to get something he might need.  When called on it, the devs don't see a problem with it.  We're a small company and should all be on the same team.  Seriously, 9:30 is not very early.  Am I really being unreasonable?

Comment: @JacobG I can't say if you're being unreasonable without more info, however the key to flex time is that the work ***must*** be getting done.  If what you're saying is the work is **not** getting done, stripping flex-time from the unproductive employees (or docking pay/vacation time) may be the way to go.  In your example. Dev X and Designer Y should be coordinating so neither is sitting twiddling their thumbs waiting on the other.  If that's not happening that's a process problem as much as a schedule problem...

Comment: `you will lose your good ones to other employment` - that's the heart of the whole issue, @Jacob.  If work isn't getting done, then you have deeper issues; your devs and designers need to coordinate better.  If work *is* getting done, then don't waste developers' time with nonsense like setting a specific start time.

Comment: +1 for losing to other employers.  If I were going from an environment where I was trusted to keep my own schedule and get my work done to a clock-punching environment where I got tardiness demerits, I'd be dusting off my resume.

Comment: @ErikDietrich:  So, if you were not getting your work done in a satisfactory manner and your boss said "You know, your work isn't getting done in a timely manner and so-and-so is complaining that you're not available enough during their set and prescribed schedule, so let's start coming in on a consistent schedule by 9:30 at the latest." would you still dust off your resume?

Comment: @JacobG  If I were coming from a flex hours environment and now part of "satisfactory" is "being on time", then absolutely I would (and, I think, so will your team).  Flex hours isn't a matter of gamers to play video games all night - it's about a culture of trust.  If it's my team, I trust them to know their own personalities and preferred work hours well enough to get things done.  Rescinding the flex hours means rescinding that trust and sending the message that they need to be (micro) managed because they're lazy and incompetent.  Even if it's true, they won't like it.

Comment: Agree with @AdamRackis about if `The big issue is that if Dev X is working on a project with Designer Y and Designer Y is in at 8, he's waiting [...]` I'd vote Designer Y should plan ahead and say at the end of day "Hey I'm going to be working on this tomorrow morning, could you make sure to get in early tomorrow and help me, or get it done before you leave"  Getting them to work together also requires less of your time.

Comment: "Oversleeping three times a week because they're playing WoW all night isn't legit."  What does "oversleeping" mean?  Are we still in grade school here?  Eight hours is eight hours, whether it starts at 6 a.m. or 10 a.m.  If you need people to be present for meetings and such, then let them pick certain core hours in which they'll be available, say 10 a.m. to 3 p.m. or whatever.  But whether the work is getting done is orthogonal to whether they come in by a certain time or not.  **Have you tried talking to the developers about the problem and asking *them* to come up with a solution?**

Comment: @Kyralessa - If your boss says to be at work at 9:30 then you better be in the office at 9:30 otherwise YOU ARE LATE.  I can't believe how many people have a problem with this author's question, let alone telling him he is not being a reasonable leader, I was taught to show up on time every single day.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that the previous culture was one in which 9:35 was NOT late, and the OP want to shift to a culture that it is, presumably for people with talents that are not easily replaceable and who have some level of freedom about where they can work.
He can shout "YOU ARE LATE," I suppose, but that may result in some people leaving and lower morale, which it sounds like he is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Renan It's not ideal for all situations, certainly.  The point is to be sure that the business needs are covered.  If there is an urgent production issue at a critical time, someone needs to be able to fix it.  In my current role, this is often me, but what happens is that I get an e-mail on my phone, I acknowledge it, and I jump on my machine *at home* and fix the issue.  If emergency after emergency happens, there are problems far beyond who is in the office when.

Comment: @Ramhound Setting an arbitrary start time when there was not one before and expecting everyone to just adjust their whole life schedule around it _is_ unreasonable. For that matter, setting a hard start time when it isn't really necessary is also unreasonable. Obviously, the developers don't see it as necessary, therefore it seems unreasonable to them. Also, considering they've been with the company much longer than the manager and they all seem to agree, they might just be right.

Answer (score 49):

The precise answer to your question is to fire and replace somebody who doesn't get the message and then fire anybody else who doesn't get the message.

I don't expect this would help your career or your company's development goals but you've decided this is the issue and it appears there's no convincing you otherwise. So that's how to do it.

More constructively, I would suggest you consider the following:

- Your devs had flex time. Now you want to take it away

It doesn't matter whether it's an official benefit in some written policy or not. It's a de facto policy and a part of the established culture. People's lives and schedules have been established around these hours. And for devs like myself, who much prefer dodging rush hour and who get a horrendously nasty case of SAD in the winter, but can't think of any dev-friendly places closer to the equator I'd rather live, it's as big of a deal as pulling health benefits.

- What is the nature of this "angst" you mention? Is it a) primarily jealousy or b) legit interdepartmental communications issues like difficulty scheduling meetings/general communication.

a) Devs don't need to interact with customers or other businesses. In my experience, the more rigid the company structure, the more mediocre the devs. While much of development is nuts and bolts, it is also a creative problem solving process that requires people be at their sharpest. It's also an unpredictable deadline driven process that results in very, very late hours at times. A side-effect of this is that devs often get the "creative" treatment. In a 30 person company it shouldn't be hard to insist people be adults about employees that need to be at their sharpest when present and are likely to ultimately put a lot more hours in over the course of a year than a 9-5er that's usually packing their things at 4:55 p.m. every day.

b) In a company of 30, you should not be having so many meetings that this becomes a problem. Not counting things like sprint meetings or other bi-monthly planning sessions, tying your devs down for more than 30 minutes every day in meetings is an absurd, grossly incompetent waste of money. Likewise with general communication. 30 people means you walk over to the other guy and talk to him. In flex time scenarios it is reasonable to set a span of time where everybody is in the office at the same time. I can't think of a good reason for that span to be more than 3-4 hours of the work day and why it shouldn't be as close to the middle of the day as possible.

- Why a morning standup?

Why is it that the first idea management scraps from scrum, agile, etc... is always the advice that you not have the standup first thing? In programming it takes a while to ramp back up to the full awareness of all the details and issues you're dealing with on a given problem. When you do standups first-thing, your devs aren't going to have their heads completely screwed on. Standups are critical to communication and improving efficiency, not something you just do first thing to "get out of the way."

- Are your devs failing to get the job done?

If not, why mess with a good thing? It's not their job to communicate with the other concerns at the company. It's yours. In a sane management structure, your accountability is to your immediate manager and the people you manage, not the sour grapes of other departments who have to be there at more typical hour for practical reasons.

Comment: I gave an answer to the question. And then a really long followup/addendum.

Answer (score 46):

### Review of the Question: There is lots of missing context and information

> As a new technical lead in a new company, what are some additional
>   strategies to employ to change the culture of the development team so
>   that people show up at the time that I've requested?

1. How new of a technical lead?
2. Why are you imposing purely non-technical managerial policies?
3. What are your management credentials?
4. What previous personnel management experience do you have?
5. Have you earned the respect of the team in a technical manner?
6. Have you earned the respect of the team in a managerial manner?

> TLDR: My team doesn't show up on time. I've tried to compel them and
>   it isn't working.

Can't provide a solution unless we know **specifically why** you need to change the culture so drastically. We also don't know **what** you have *tried to compel* them with either to be able to tell you *why* it is ineffective. [We can guess](http://youtu.be/gx4jn77VKlQ?t=15s), but that is speculation.

Why are you tasked with solving what is arguably a non-technical personel management mandate? Hand it over to a superior who is a manager and let them deal with it. Good Cop vs Bad Cop.

> Background Data:
>
> Small company, 30 employees, 5 members of my team. The previous lead
>   is still on staff as a regular developer.

1. Did the previous technical lead step down?
2. Was the previous technical lead demoted?
3. Was the previous technical lead effective?
4. Does the majority of the existing team have a more personal relationship with the previous technical lead?
5. Is the previous technical lead *effectively still in charge*?

> The culture prior to my
>   arrival was one of informality with no set boundaries or core hours.
>   This culture was not challenged by the corporate leaders.

1. Then it must have been working?
2. Was the team successful in delivering useful products when promised?

> Most people
>   on the team would show up between 10:30 and 11:00 because of this.
>   Other departments, due to the nature of their work, have set start
>   times of either 8 or 9. This discrepancy and unpredictability causes a
>   lot of angst between my department and other departments.

Specifically how so, there is not enough detail here to even begin to formulate an answer to this question. Any kind of answer would be complete speculation.

> As such, I sat the team down and specified a 'no later than' time of 9:30. I
>   explained my reasoning and I explained the benefits of such a scheme
>   and the negatives of the current scheme. It was a long and contentious
>   conversation and 3 of the 5 people on the team were quite displeased.

How about giving us your *benefits* and *negatives* without them, we can't judge how reasonable nor how effective your communication may have been. Doesn't sound like you even considered or explored some kind of compromise with your team or the external teams based on their negative feed back. Did you?

> Needless to say, people aren't showing up on time (and 9:35 is not on time.)

This doesn't sound like a very positive or effective attitude.

> I've scheduled our daily standup meeting at 9:30 as an added
>   motivator. Knowing that it takes a little bit of time to transition
>   start times (with commute, etc...) I initially would wait to begin the
>   meeting until everyone showed up, but now **I just start the meeting
>   (and often finish the meeting) with whomever is present.** That seems to
>   not be making a difference either and **it's making the team less
>   cohesive.**

So unilateral actions **you** are taking are making the team less cohesive. Think about *it*.

> Conversations on an individual and group basis yield the same results
>   as the original conversation (i.e. they don't see the value, think I'm
>   taking away a perk of the job, etc...)

We hear and can extrapolate what they don't accept, do you *hear* them?

> I have the full support and backing of the senior management team and
>   am empowered to employ whatever devices I feel appropriate to get this
>   taken care of.

The Catholic Church had the same power during the Inquisition, look at how that turned out!

> My current next step is to send someone home and make them take the
>   day off. Is that too drastic? Are there alternative strategies that
>   I'm overlooking that could help me solve this problem?

Escalation doesn't sound like a viable alternative either. Sending them home without pay is insulting and will hurt the company **more** than the employee. It will make you look even more dictatorial and tyrannical. Treating them like children will just make them act like children even more.

---

## Predicted outcome of your current approach

1. You will lose all respect from the entire team, they will be more and more ineffective, you will be perceived more and more ineffective as productivity grinds to a halt.
2. Your failure with policy change and personell management skills will cause you to be perceived ineffective to your superiors.
3. You will lose respect from people *not* on your team because of interoffice communication. It will sabotage any future technical leadership opportunities with them as well.
4. You will damage your reputation at the company for sure, up and down the chain.
5. The better employees will vocally quit first.
6. The even better employees will quietly quit after them.
7. The marginally qualified ones may quit or may not depending on the pain you impose.
8. The unqualified ones will hang on like ticks and endure whatever you impose.
9. The company ends up losing, and getting a bad reputation externally by the employees that left.
10. Perception is everything! Never forget that!

#### Some suggested approaches

1. As their manager you should fight to insulate them from upper management decisions. You should fight for their voice to be heard. You should help them collectively form a response and push back and support them with their response.
2. This is a non-technical decision and purely a corporate management one. Why are you dealing with it and its implementation? Have a superior deal with this, that is their job.
3. Don't act like a dictator or tyrant. Might does not equal right.
4. Take some people skills, soft skills training.
5. Move more slowly. Things like this don't change over night.
6. You need to get the previous technical lead on your side if they have a rapport with the team.
7. Have an alternative compromise, how about the people that don't mind coming in early do it, the other people don't have to?
8. The move of the stand up time is arbitrary, everyone sees this and isn't seen as practical or reasonable but as dictatorial.
9. Have the external teams that you have to deal with be part of the discussion and help you sell the policy changes.
10. Back off, agree with them, be the Good Cop. Get your superior to lay down the law. This is a management problem, *not* a technical problem. Your are technical lead not a manager right?
11. Have the external team members and your team members just work out times to meet when they need to meet. Predetermined days and times of availability would be a good compromise. The developers don't want to be constantly interrupted by the external team and appear to be there solely to jump to meetings at their demand.

### Final Thought:

My Management Style both technical and non-technical is based on [Wu Wei Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_wei) of The Tao te Ching.

> The Wu Wei principle can be understood by striking at a piece of cork
>   floating in water. The harder you hit it, the more it yields: the more
>   it yields, the harder it bounces back. Without expending energy, the
>   cork can easily wear you out.

The more you do the quicker you are likely to fail. The less you do the more likely the thing you want to happen will get done.

#### Indirect Transparent Leadership

> At first, at best, 
>   people hardly notice a leader. 
>   Next they adore and
>   acclaim him, 
>   then come to fear him, 
>   in the end despise him. 
>   Thus lost faith breeds lost faith.
>
> Be nondirective, make your few words precious. When the work is done,
>   end gained, everyone will say: We did it by ourselves, naturally.

Get the external department people that have the complaints together with your people in a room and let them hash out an acceptable solution between themselves internally, *without you in the room*. Be willing to accept whatever the outcome is. Then the solution is theirs, they own it, and you will gain some badly needed respect from them for letting them work it out. This is the **nondirective** approach.

Comment: +1, These are all really great approaches.  Personally, I like the approach of empowering  the team solve the problem. It's amazing what adults are capable of when they're treated like ... well ... adults. Martha needs to meet with John, so they plan and coordinate together, without the big mean nasty boss to come in and play dictator.

Comment: I've edited my question to answer some of your specific questions.

Comment: @JacobG Even after your edit, one thing that still isn't clear is are you a *Technical Lead* or are you these peoples *Non-Technical Lead/Line Manager*? This is an important distinction, as a Technical Lead, leads in technical decision making. What **technology** to use, **not** when the developers come into work! 10 years of making technical decisions isn't any kind of qualifications for dealing with non-technical managerial social/personality issues like this, especially with no formal training.

Comment: @JacobG You started with the *stick* approach, no amount of *carrots* will recover from that. A mark of a great leader is to know when they aren't qualified and aren't going to be effective and ask for help, I personally think this is one of those moments for you to save face and punt this battle off to someone else. You have lost the war psychologically, even if you *win* the battle you and the team will have mutually lost. The **only** way you might resolve this is to get the leaders of the external depts together with your team and have them hash out a solution *without* you in the room.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - I'm not sure I understand your distinction.  I'm responsible for controlling the technical direction and I'm also responsible for their reviews.  I approve PTO and I deliver features.  I've been doing both of those things for 10 years.  Further, there technically hasn't been a "stick" approach.  This policy was put in place via a 2+ hour discussion with the entire team.  It was not presented dictatorially and there have been no consequences.  The executives have since reinforced the message with the team and basically had the same 2+ hour discussion.

Comment: @JacobG *"was put in place via a 2+ hour discussion"* is a oxymoron. *"was put in place"* implies a **unilateral** decision dictated by someone and applied. Most places I have worked in the past 22+ years realized that there should be a separation of Technical leadership and management. This is a very well established organizational structure in most large ( I mean multi-billion $$$ a year ) companies I have worked for as technical leadership. Conflating the two responsibilities is a recipe for strife. Having 2X 2+ hour *discussions* should tell you the policy is bad and the approach is worse.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I think we're talking across each other.  1) This company is way too small to warrant a non-technical development manager.  2) This question really boils down to "how to influence a culture change" regardless of the specifics of the change.  The fact is, the folks in charge recognize the need for a cultural shift and have come to a conclusion as to what the shift is.  Everyone involved agrees that the shift is correct.  The hope was that discussing it with the dev team would result in them drawing the same conclusions.  That didn't happen and this fiasco is the result.

Comment: +1 this is a good answer... though I prefer a more structured environment this is an actual answer with practical suggestions.

Comment: @JacobG: "Everyone involved agrees that the shift is correct." Yet you said that 3 out of 5 of the developers strongly objected to the change. Does this mean that the developers aren't "involved" in the shift? Or do you mean that after the discussions, all the developers agreed that this change was necessary?

Comment: @MarkBannister - Sorry for the confusion.  I meant that everyone in charge that determined the need for a cultural shift agreed that this was an appropriate move.

Comment: @JacobG you keep saying *you discussed it with them*, you didn't you told them how it was going to be now and apparently there was an argument for 2+ hours. That isn't a *discussion* about a policy shift. **A real discussion** would have been *we have the following complaints from other departments, one idea from those teams is an earlier start time, what other ideas do you guys have that we can float back to the other teams to to resolve the actual issues they have?*. Since it doesn't seem that having everyone 100% of the team there early is actually the problem.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: I feel like I'm still not being clear. Leadership recognized systemic, cultural problem, devised solution via extensive discussion. The punctuality component was one element of that solution. The discussion with the dev team was to lead them through the same logic that brought leadership to their conclusions with the expectation that the team would draw the same conclusions. That did not happen because the team did not agree that there was a problem to be solved. They opted to focus on this particular issue above all others.

Comment: @JacobG a discussion implies bi-lateral communication, by your own admission even here, this was a unilateral communication of *how things are going to be now*. *"I've scheduled our daily standup meeting at 9:30 as an added motivator."* is an arbitrary **stick** trying to force compliant behavior. Everyone reading this perceives that, your "team" perceived that for sure! It is a rule that was put in place that they see as a punishment for actions not yet taken and are rebelling. If you won't accept this perception, nothing you do will be effective. You are clear, you aren't listening to them.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I really don't know why we're not connecting here. If 5 depts complain about 1 (real/valid) and the 1 thinks the 5 are just jealous/inferior/should get over it, then attempting to convince them why this change would be better for everyone seems fair. Like I've said, senior mgmt asked me to put the change in place, I attempted to walk the team through the logic that senior mgmt walked through and the response was that there was really no problem. Am I supposed to go back to mgmt and say "sorry guys, dev team thinks customer service is a bunch of babies and should get over it?"

Comment: @JacobG my point is **your approach** to the dev team was poor. If you insist on this approach, which it sounds like you do, **you will continue to fail** and your supervisors will see you failing. I do think you should push back on behalf of your team, *a large part of a managers job* is to insulate their team from things like this. You should at least give the dev team a chance to work out an alternative solution to push back with. I have given many **successful** approaches to coming up with a mutual compromise. I don't believe the **entire** team needs to be at their beck and call.

Comment: @JacobG stop spending so much time defending your failed approach and justifying the other departments opinions and start taking all the good suggestions on **how you can support your team and let their voice be heard!** If you don't think they should have a voice, well I wouldn't want to be on that team. See my predictions on what is going to happen in my answer.

Comment: Reading this discussion, it occurs to me that the real problem here is that higher-ups are making determinations on details that shouldn't concern them. Every tier should concern itself with inadequate results from the tier below it. The how should be in your court. That the devs are pretty much blowing everyone off at this point suggests to me that they are both fed up and not at all worried about finding new jobs if it comes to that. If they want to play it like that, they'd best gauge the difficulty of replacing most of a dev team.

Answer (score 28):

The first thing you need to do is [go read "Peopleware"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633439)

It is a mistake to try to change this now.  I was a manager at a company where we had a pretty flexible work schedule.  One of our most productive developers came in at 11am.  He reported to me for a while.  I was told to get him to change his hours.  I fought this request.  Hard.  I was overruled.

The result:

A less productive, less interested developer who was a huge team contributor.  He became far less productive and useful for the team.

All because of some silly notion of "on time".

Focus more on productivity.

Your job as manager is to remove barriers to productivity - not make everyone look, feel and act the same.

Flexible hours are a perk - and an employer who allows flexible hours can attract more quality people.

As a "new technical lead" there is no way you can change culture soon.  Especially in the direction you seem to want.  Have you done anything to improve your team's roles/jobs?

Work on building trust with them first.  So many first time managers/leads make mistakes like this.

**Find out what the other groups REALLY need.  Not "they have to be here at 9:30".  Really find out what the issue is.  Then find a solution to that.**

**Instead of telling your team what to do - explain the issue and then ASK THEM FOR SUGGESTIONS/FEEDBACK.**

You make a vague reference to "causes a lot of angst between my department and other departments" - but it is unclear what that angst is - are they upset that devs are treated preferentially?  What is the real underlying issue?

> I've tried to compel them and it isn't working.

There's a reason for that.  And you don't seem to be listening.  Reaching for more drastic measure and bigger hammers are not really going to improve the situation.  Try the "carrot" approach instead of the "stick" approach.

Again, read "Peopleware".

You are not going to go far with ideas like daily meetings or sending people home or with the notion that they are your minions who need to do as you say, "or else."

Who is telling you they need to be at work at 9:30?  Other groups?  Your bosses?  You?  Figure out the REAL issue and address that.  When they show up should NOT be the issue.

Comment: *Moderator note: extended discussion in comments has been cleared.  For any continued discussion, please take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler).*

Comment: I had a colleague once who turned up at 12 o'clock and left when he felt like it. Wearing either sandals or no shoes at all. As a software developer, he was tremendous. He was one of very few people I ever met who was clearly better at this job than me. Trying to force this guy to start early would (a) not succeed, and (b) be the most ridiculously stupid thing you could ever do.

Answer (score 20):

Regardless of why you're doing it, to your team members it feels like you're taking away a perk. To some of them it may even be one of the major reasons why they're working for your company rather than another one.

Essentially, you're asking them to take a reduction in their total compensation package.

It's possible to convince them to take it, but you'll need good arguments and there almost certainly will be lingering resentment about it. You may or may not lose good people over this.

From your description the main reason appears to be jealousy from other departments. Have you considered giving the other departments the same perk?

In short: Don't do it unless you think it's worth losing some of them over it.

Comment: It isn't exclusively jealousy and my mistake if I characterized it as such.  Other departments have public-facing business hours, so flex time without adding resources isn't really a possibility for them.

Comment: @Chad - The answer is implicit in the second paragraph: Pay them more

Comment: @CurtainDog  - Unless the pay raise is contingent upon showing up on time then I doubt this will be a lasting solution.  If it is contingent then we kind of agree.

Comment: Would it be possible to edit this post and expand on how to give the other team the same perk? While this post does offer an alternative, it doesn't really go into depth or address the fact that some of the employees may be shift workers who must have a schedule.

Answer (score 18):

To change your culture you need to realize why you are experiencing resistance and then manage the cause of the resistance.

In my experience, "coordinating with other departments" tends to be the province of those with higher position titles and headed down a project/people management track.  Work-a-day devs interested only in code tend to be shielded from this.  In more structured shops, they may not do it at all and in smaller shops, they may do it more informally.

Like it or not, you've inherited a flex hours culture, which is a huge perk for most developers.  Taking that away from them in one of your first acts as leader not will not only seem tyrannical to them (when you explain to them that 9:30 isn't *that* early, you're imposing your own schedule on them, arbitrarily in their opinion), but is realistically the subtraction of a substantial perk.  You may like working a particular schedule and not consider this to be a meaningful perk, but they probably consider it invaluable.  Consider this on par with telling them you're taking away a week of their vacation or cutting their pay by a few percent.

To change that, you can use the carrot or the stick.  You're talking about using a stick and, maybe, a bigger stick.  If you go that route, I'd plan to hire a few new developers, as I'm guessing that some of your team is going to start going on interviews at other companies.  I would personally go the carrot route in order to get buyin for removal of this perk by making it clear that future promotions and advancements will be decided by those who "coordinate with other departments".  That is, leaders/important people are in early, working with other teams, taking on responsibilities, etc.  "Newbies" get the flex perk, but people serious about advancing get in on time.

If you create that culture, I suspect that some of your devs will start coming in on time of their own accord.  Both due to interest in advancement and due to the perception that "the important people get in early."

Answer (score 13):

The short answer is that you should NOT do this.  Your technical team members are (or at least, *should be*) smart enough to know that there is no tangible benefit to having everyone present at the office by some arbitrary time; the *only* important metric is whether or not their work gets done.

If your team is not getting their work done, then that is a separate issue.  But if they are getting things done, then why are you harassing them just because other departments have been harassing you?

Part of your role as a leader is to insulate your team from trivial distractions and criticisms brought about by external sources.  If your reaction to other people complaining about your team members is to pass the complaints on to your team members and/or dictate changes based solely upon those complaints, then you are failing at your job.  I'd suggest that, assuming that your team is in fact getting its job(s) done (which it sounds like they are, since you make no complaints about their productivity), a better way to respond to such criticism is to tell the complainer "yes, well my guys work hard and consistently deliver solid results, and that's the only thing that matters; so why don't you stop worrying about how my team handles their tasks and get back to your own?".

And of course, if you do go through with a mandatory "you must be in the office by time X" policy, it's only fair to complement it with a "you must leave the office by time Y" policy, and a "you must not work from home outside of normal business hours" policy.  That's only fair as a way to protect your employee's work/life balance, as I bet many of the team members you have who do not show up until 11:00 are probably either staying back late or putting in extra time at home.

Comment: Except the author claims work isn't getting done.

Comment: @Ramhound - No he doesn't, at least not in the original post.  In the laundry-list of edits he mentions that performance has been on the decline recently.  But as the team has always had flexible working hours in the past, there's still nothing to show that the decline of performance is correlated to working hours, or that setting a firm start time will cause any improvement.  Judging from the original post is seems like the author is most concerned about the negative feedback that he gets from other departments.

Comment: Sounds like "the beatings will continue until morale improves".

Answer (score 13):

I don't envy you this one - as a fellow manager, it would be hard for me. And quite honestly, I believe you are going to lose people over it. I think you have a single symptom that comes from the Start Up -> Medium Sized culture shift, and not every developer is going to make this change successfully. I think you need to be prepared with job descriptions and knowledge of how you open job requests and I think you need to put emphasis on the ability to hire new people and improve documentation...

Sorry that's so grim.  But I don't think you have a situation of trust issues, or a case where you can easily explain people into agreement.  And there really is no compensation that perfectly balances massive flexibility on the job.

I agree that you ARE taking away a perk.  Flexibility in start time is a big deal for some people, and it speaks to an informal culture that can be a strong preference for some folks.  Presumably as the company has grown, workload has become more reliable, job security has improved, respect for the product has increased, and you may have been able to offer some nifty stock plans, pay raises or other improvements.  If none of that is true, then you have ask yourself if you have a growing & thriving company or a company plunging into despair.

Trick is, people often can't connect the dots between these new value-adds and the removal of the favorite perk.  You can try explaining it, but for some people this is not a good tradeoff, and this is not a case where you can offer the choice.  It's a "my way or the highway" since it's having an organizational impact that can't necessarily be felt within the team, but which is experienced and supported at the higher levels of the company.

It sounds like you've done the right things:

- you've laid it out clearly
- you've talked about the reason and need for change
- you've engaged one on one (and continue to do so, I presume) to fix individual cases as they come up
- you've given feedback

I think you're down to the "does he really mean it?" point where it's mostly proving to people that you are serious, and that this really needs to change.  It'd be my personal opinion that being 5 minutes late in an office in my region is not a big deal and that meetings that have a short span (like stand ups in an agile sprint) shouldn't be so smack up against the start of the work day that a missed bus connection or bad traffic is going to be a regular problem.  But this is somewhat regional - different locales have wide variations in the traffic situation.  So that's as much knowing your region and knowing from individual complaints what's reasonable.

The rest is just coming up with a mechanism that is debilitating enough to prove that you are serious.  A day of docked pay is one option and it is within your legal rights - although any mechanism I'd come up with I'd run through the lawyers.  So is a formal warning system that leads to discplinary action.  I'd assume that your HR department might have suggestions...

A lot depends on what the work can tolerate - when you send someone home, you also loose out on that day's work, which impacts your cost & schedule.  When you have a warning system that leads to disciplinary action - including termination - you save the rest of the day's work, but risk having to fire the employee.

I think the thing is, when you deal with punishments, you have to be prepared with a punishment that is damaging enough to be taken seriously and to drive home the point that "you are not doing your job if you are not doing this".

Answer (score 10):

It seems that there's a disconnect here between how your developers see the issue, and how the other departments (or your superiors, or whoever it is that's actually demanding this change) see the issue.  I would suggest trying to bridge that gap, in multiple stages if necessary.

First, do the developers agree that there are good reasons for this change? If they disagree, do they have any good counter-arguments, or alternative suggestions? If they do, you should bring those to the management and see if they'll relax the timing requirement - or if they can explain why the alternatives won't work and the counter-arguments don't solve the issue, so that you can go back to your developers and give them a more complete explanation. Continue the back-and-forth as long as necessary/productive.

If you get to the point where the developers agree that there are good reasons but just aren't willing to adapt, or they don't think the reasons are good and resent the whole idea, *communicate that to management*. Explain that you *could* force the developers to do what is wanted, but it will cause resentment, lower motivation, quite possibly lower productivity or even employees leaving. Make sure the management understands this and still agrees that it's important to enforce the start time (and again, communicate this to your developers), otherwise you may end up responsible for a change that lost the company more than it gained.

<sub>*(A personal note: I've been in the position of being told to come in at a set hour for, as far as the employees were concerned, no good reason, and it's really extremely unmotivating. It's really important to make sure people understand the reasons and don't feel like you're just changing the policy on a whim or because you don't trust them.)*</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I used to work at a non-profit that had this problem. Meetings always started late, 10 minutes late became a "standard".

Then we got a new project manager for a big key project (and one on a fixed timeline). She called the first meeting. People strolled in as usual, minutes late and casually chatting. She sat in her chair and said nothing - nothing at all - for several minutes. Eventually the chatting "died down" until there was silence. We were all waiting for hear to speak. She allowed the silence to continue for a little longer. They she looked around and said "I need to make it clear. Meetings start on time. If you're going to be 5 minutes late, don't bother coming, just see me afterwards. OK, now for the project we're doing this week [whatever]...". This made a BIG impression and people made a real effort to be on time for her meetings.

*Note: Added additional answer below.*

> **Account for work done remotely.**

Often the highest producers do a large part of their work **remotely** anyway, so they're sometimes putting in as much time remotely as in the office. This is an important point to both consider and communicate with the other departments. That communication should be subtle - don't call a meeting, just start looking for ways to show "yeah, joe was up late last night working on x" and "yeah, Mary fixed that on Sunday, she was up 'till like midnight'.

Talk openly about the commute. If someone comes in at 10.30, their commute may be 15 mins. If they needs to be in at 9 or 9.30 their commute could be an hour. Plus it would be the same going home if they worked 8 or 9 hours.  Many people feel this is a major waste of their life. They'd rather work remotely for a bit and then come in after that. Look to integerate this fact with your needs when setting times and make sure other departments know about that too, again by mentioning it frequently.

Make sure you use **technology** to help. For instance I work virtually - 100% of the time. So having Skype on, showing my status as online, a video-cam, etc. can help too.

Comment: The reason I'm upvoting this is because the idea of the manager is great - she practically gave everybody a "get out of meetings free card".

Answer (score 8):

Having been in similar situations, though admittedly in less time than the OP, I only have this to say about the state of his situation:

### The most practical and simplest solution...

...would be to try start the meetings at 11 o' clock instead. Don't worry, you're not "giving in". Instead you're redirecting the flow much like the principles behind [Aikido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aikido). The idea is to instead focus on enabling your team to get important things done as it is the paramount point because there really is one serious problem that needs to be adressed:

**The team really has NO idea what is up with the other departments and what they REALLY need to do.**

Having your team to show up at 9:30 which I can admit is not early is however not a solution to this problem. You have tried and failed so [stop insisting to do so](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYLMTvxOaeE). Stop banging your head on a brick wall. My only tip here is to always value communication over arbitrarily set meetings.

Since the other departments start at 8 you can **use this late team meeting to your own advantage**. Between 8 and 11 you have **3 hours** to help your team with project management activities such as (in no particular order or priority):

- Go to meetings and gather goals and requirements from the other departments
- Figure out what was finished since yesterday
- Manage expectations and commitments with the other departments on what needs to and can be done during the work day
- Deliver good news and bad news to the other departments
- Update any plans relevant to the team if there are any
- Figure out what code and software architecture issues needs to have attention today
- Saying "NO" to requests that do not provide any business value
- Accept criticism from the other apartments and apologize with assurance that issues will be fixed
- etc. *(there is always something that needs to be addressed)*

And finally before the meeting *summarize a brief* for the team on what is happening, in order to give them some situational awareness. When the meeting starts at 11 and everyone is fresh to get to work you have information and a meeting protocol prepared for them. You can have the brief and minutes from the meeting written like a newsletter and send it as an email sometime after the meeting as a gentle reminder.

During the meeting with the team you need two things from them:

- Ask for **estimations** for tasks that need to be done, especially those that are in high priority. It doesn't have to be precise, as in minutes. With this you can decide commitments and deadlines much more clearly with the other departments. If they can't give any estimation for a task, ask them to figure it out during the day or the next.
- Ask for **impediments** or if they need help with anything, write that down and see to it if those issues are fixable and that they get fixed.

After a while you can probably gradually move to have the meetings earlier. But initially going against the grain is not the way to go and only lead to even more infectious culture (in which the only way to repair is to replace the whole team). **If they are, as you say, "primadonnas" then your real job is to refurbish them into awesome primadonnas that deliver with high quality.** It is clear that your team had and wants [autonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomy), so start exploiting that culture to the advantage of your company's goals.

When you've managed to make a dependable team, through communication rather than coercion, you can leave three hours earlier than everyone else in the team knowing they're doing their job (but still be on call if the crap hits the fan). **Now that's trust that you can count on.**

Comment: I think this is more good solid advice, and a good alternative approach that would lead to success. The role of a **manager/team leader** is to insulate the team from noise and confusion and remove obstacles that reduce their efficiency. This answer proposes an approach to do all those things!

Answer (score 6):

The others raise a lot of good points about how to handle the situation; however, at the end of the day, if the schedule of your group is disrupting others in the company then you must correct the problem and ensure that things run smoothly. With this in mind, you need to find out when other groups need reliable access to the developers and if there is any room for flexibility in that schedule. If other groups need access to developers when they are at the office on an unpredictable basis then a core segment of developers need to make sure that need is accommodated. If this means that some developers have to be at the office at fixed periods of time, then it is what it is.

With regards to moving the developers to some sort of a fixed availability schedule, your best bet is to ensure that any "hard hours" are softened as much as possible. For example, if the "core hours" are from 11:00 to 15:00 then you can also make sure that the core hours on Friday are not present and Friday is a true flex time day. As Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday are traditionally considered the most productive days of the week you might be able to have the core hours apply to those days and allow Monday and Friday to be full flex days as well.

In terms of ensure that the hours are adhered to, if the direction comes down from the top and is approved by upper management then ultimately the developers must adhere to it as part of their employment. You should do what you can to ensure that it is phased in and if some developers have flex-time written into their employment agreement it should be addressed (eg. by changing their compensation and benefits, grandfathering them in, etc.); however, at some point you are going to have to ensure that the policy needs to be adhered to which may also require official disciplining of employees. Likewise, if some choose to leave it may be worth trying to see if they are willing to stay with compensation and benefits changes; however you may also have to accept losing some of the developers.

Ultimately, if your job requires that you enforce a cultural change to the group to meet the needs of the business then you options are going to be limited to an extent. You can and should do everything to soften the change and elicit any compromises with other groups as you can, but eventually you will need to enforce the change and accept any personnel change that may come with it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm reading comments and answers and I have to confess, I'm a bit flabbergasted. Since when is having people show up on time "loss of a perk"? Since when is flex-time not having to care about the impact of your actions on the rest of the team and company?

From what I read in the question and comments, the behavior of his team-members is provably detrimental and costly to the company. And after trying to reason and compromise, the situation has not improved (and btw, 9.30 is **not** early or in any way unreasonable).

Explain to your team that you have no problem with flex-time, but that it implies a certain amount of personal responsibility to make sure your flexing is not impacting the work of others (on your team or other teams). As your team is clearly failing on the responsibility part, I would say that effective immediately and until further notice, all flex-time has to be approved by you beforehand. Failure to show up on time in the morning without approval or a reasonable excuse (no, alarm-clock did not go off is not acceptable) **will** result in disciplinary action like docking pay or vacation time.

Be very clear why this is happening and what has forced you to take these measures. Point out that this is not something you **want** to do, but something that you have been **forced** to do. Also be clear that these restrictive policies can be lifted once the situation improves.

Comment: **Comments removed.** Please use comments to improve the answer or request clarification, not for general discussion. For extended discussion, please use [chat].

Answer (score 2):

There are still multiple avenues available to you for handling this issue one of which would be to change the role that the department plays such as for example: If you are working with software developers you could change the role for a certain or people during the week to have them do support for the other departments, which requires 1 or more to come in at 9 or earlier and if that doesn't work you could always invoke an insubordination clause which normally is present in any employment handbook **in the US**.  Personally I've always been against using this clause, which gives a manager an avenue to reprimand and even fire someone **for cause** but in your case this may be appropriate.  So review the **employee handbook** and discuss it with your superior if you have any that you will be doing this.

The basic idea is as follows:

1. You set the rule that at least 1-2 or all people should be at work by hour X.
2. If your team members don't have a valid excuse not to show up or persist in this practice you as manager should reprimand them and possibly fire them.

As a manager doing what I described would be the **last resort** but based on what you are describing you may have reached that point.  There are many articles on could constitute employee insubordination that you can find online and these are just a few examples:

- [BlogSpot](http://work-law.blogspot.com/2011/04/what-does-insubordination-mean-anyway.html)
- [Duhaime](http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/I/Insubordination.aspx)

Of course the unfortunate consequence may be high rate of turn over in your group which would poorly reflect on you as a manager but it will enforce the discipline and likely kill morale in the process.

Now having said all of that I do have one question:  Do you really need your team to be in earlier then when they come in?

Comment: In response to your question - Yes.  We have multiple departments with whom we work regularly.  These departments are in between 8-9 and leave between 4:30-5:30.  A late start time and lunch means, at a minimum - 1) No meetings before 1pm and 2) Wasting half of a day or more if someone is waiting on something from our department.  Incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @JacobG the classic consequence is "You stay late to finish the work, or we dock vacation time".  With respect to "everyone" finding 9:30 a reasonable start time: I don't. Then again, I work until 8-9 at night, sometimes later, and often after I've gone home.  Those are my most productive hours, and I wouldn't put them in if I were expected to walk in the door at 0930 sharp "or else" - I'd become a 9-to-5er.  Every team is unique, and I hope you're considering that in your evaluation...

Comment: @Jacob - what sort of dev team is this?  Are you guys just another company maintaining the internal X app, or are these high-quality developers writing solid code that's the backbone of your company?  If the latter, some of them expecting to be able to work late from home and come in late seems unsurprising.  I would suggest you try to accommodate that.  Quality developers are *incredibly* hard to find.  And they always have other options if the current job isn't working out.

Comment: @voretaq7 don't take this the wrong way, but I find that largely a matter of habit. If you get into the habit of going to bed at 11PM instead of 3AM and getting up at 7AM instead of 9:30 you'll find that after a while, your most productive time will be before lunch and that at 9PM, you'll start to get a bit sleepy. Humans adapt.

Comment: @JacobG Why is it 'wasting half a day'?  Are these other teams arriving at 8am in the morning and then suddenly realising they need something from a developer?

Comment: @robertc There are certainly occasions where the other teams arrive at 8 and see that there is something that needs developer attention.  But, that wasn't my point.  My point was that if another department is blocking on something from the development team, the block will never be released until at least half way through the requestor's day.  Sometimes that's okay and many times it's just flat inconvenient.

Comment: @JacobG But you miss my point, why are they waiting until 8 in the morning on the day when they need something to decide to tell the developer they need something?

Comment: @robertc Because they don't know they need something until 8 in the morning.  "A customer called in and was experiencing this problem..." "It appears that this data is corrupted..."

Comment: @JacobG None of the examples you've listed are development tasks. Even if you're having your developers do client support (as you are implying), why do all your developers need to be in the office at a certain time to do support? Why have you promised specific turnaround times to clients and other departments on support issues when you don't have dedicated support staff?

Comment: I have worked in a handful of teams that were broken because of rules like the one suggested here. A word of advice: people may start coming in early for a few weeks. But after that you're going to see them working for the competition.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to decide what's more important, getting the job done properly or sitting at your desk for 8 hours at prescribed times?